# How can I generate 10 million random alphanumeric records in vertica sql?

Tags: java, python, sql, shell, vertica

I need to generate 100 million random alphanumeric 12 character records in the vertica database table or else any other way to generate 100mil random alphanumeric 12 character records file. Then i can load file in database. 
below are the example records

E.g: BAN1334HNAD1

```
 GEN1235NDA12
```

Comment: Java or Python?

Comment: Hi @DominiqueBarton, I need to generate in the database , even creating a flat file in any language(Java or Python) is ok.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Vertica instance to test with, but this should give you an idea:

```
with t (l) as (
  select 'A' union all select 'B' union all select 'C' union all 
  select '1' union all select '2' union all select '3'
)
select t1.l || t2.l || t3.l 
from t t1, t t2, t t3 
order by random() 
limit 10
```

Comment: This is a neat answer that ran directly for me in Vertica... but... if it is extended for A-Z and 0-9, with 12 characters, it will take a LONG time to run.  I just tried it with an output of 3 as listed and it took 125 msec, 4 took 165, 6 1659 msec, 7 took 267msec and 8 took 365,000 msec.  I don't want to wait for anything bigger than that.  I suggest preparing the data external to Vertica and running it in with a COPY.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int ii,jj;
    char list[]="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    int len=strlen(list);
    char retStr[14]={0};
    for(ii=0; ii<100*1000*1000; ii++) {
        memset(retStr,0,sizeof(retStr));
        for(jj=0; jj<12; jj++) {
            int sub=random()%len;
            retStr[jj]=list[sub];
        }
        printf("%s\n", retStr);
    }
}
```

I compiled this into a program called rand12 and created a rand12 table:

```
create table rand12 (a varchar2(12));
```

and then ran the data in with:

```
./rand12 |
~/opt/vertica/bin/vsql -c  "copy rand12 (a) from local stdin
delimiter '|' abort on error commit;"
```

This could just as easily be implemented in Java or Python.